# Running out of memory when calculating loss using SigmoidFocalCrossEntropy

Tags: python, tensorflow, loss-function, memory

Code Versions:

```py
python == 3.8
tensorflow == 2.2.0
tensorflow-addons == 0.11.2
```

Recently I've been using tensorflow addon's focal loss function for one of my models. In order to better understand/demonstrate what's going on, I've been trying to recreate some of the graphs from the [original paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1708.02002?source=post_page---------------------------) - specifically, figure 4, which shows a cumulative sum plot of the minority and majority loss separately using different gammas on a converged model.

```py
def calcCSP(pred, Y_test, g, label):

    true = np.asarray(Y_test)
    idsPos = np.where(true == 1)
    idsNeg = np.where(true == 0)

    pPos = pred[idsPos]
    yPos = true[idsPos]

    pNeg = pred[idsNeg]
    yNeg = true[idsNeg]

    if label == 1:
        p = pPos
        y = yPos
        title = "Positive Loss Distribution"
    else:
        p = pNeg
        y = yNeg
        title = "Negative Loss Distribution"

    p = tf.convert_to_tensor(p)
    y = tf.cast(y, tf.float32)

    fl = tfa.losses.SigmoidFocalCrossEntropy(alpha=PARAMS['alpha'], gamma=g)

    loss = fl(y, p)

    x = np.sort(loss)

    # Normalized Data
    x = x/sum(x)

    cdf = np.cumsum(x)
    n = len(x)
    share_of_population = np.arange(1, n + 1) / n


    cdf_materials = {"shares": share_of_population,
                     "cusum": cdf}

    return cdf_materials


cdfListPos = []
cdfListNeg = []

gammas = [0, 2, 4, 6, 8]

for g in gammas:
    # will need to store all this
    cdf_matPos = calcCDF(preds, y_test, g, 1)
    cdf_matNeg = calcCDF(preds, y_test, g, 0)
    cdfListPos.append(cdf_matPos)
    cdfListNeg.append(cdf_matNeg)

posplot = plt.figure()
for i in range(len(gammas)):
    plt.plot(cdfListPos[i]['shares'], cdfListPos[i]['cusum'], label= r'$\gamma$ = ' + str(gammas[i]))
    plt.title('Positive Points CSP')
    plt.ylabel('Cumulative Normalized Loss')
    plt.legend()

negplot = plt.figure()
for i in range(len(gammas)):
    plt.plot(cdfListNeg[i]['shares'], cdfListNeg[i]['cusum'], label=r'$\gamma$ = ' + str(gammas[i]))
    plt.title('Negative Points CSP')
    plt.ylabel('Cumulative Normalized Loss')
    plt.legend()
```

I've managed to run my code okay on smaller datasets - however, once the dataset gets too large, I seem to run out of memory.

```py
W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:434] Allocator (mklcpu) ran out of memory trying to allocate 4.47GiB (rounded to 4804430848)
Current allocation summary follows.
```

I've omitted the summary for brevity, but can add it in if necessary. I'm unsure of how to get around this. I've tried using [tf.split](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/split) to divide up the predicted and true values into smaller tensors, then passing them to the loss function separately and concatenating, but testing with a smaller dataset shows that the results don't match when I compare them to the full versions. I'm honestly stumped on how best to work around this and would be open to any recommendations.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use reduce precision. Instead of `y = tf.cast(y, tf.float32)`, use `y = tf.cast(y, tf. float16)` or `y = tf.cast(y, tf.bfloat16)`